# How to send only specific packets in git push?

Tags: git, git-push, packet, gitolite, networkstream

I have been trying to optimize git push for a while and I noticed these extra delievery of packets that we might not need and can be avoided. Note - I am behind a gitolite layer at the remote end.

So when I do a

`git push origin <ref for the commit>`,

the remote side executes a

`git receive-pack <path/to/submodule>`.

After this in trace log for the packet shows packets containing information regarding **all** the commits the repository has (which may become very large over the course of time).

The trace looks something like -

```
18:47:03.556493 pkt-line.c:80           packet:         push< <commit hash> refs/tags/commit/<commit-hash>
.
.
.
.
```

What I was expecting it to be was to send only two such packets -

1. One for the submodule commit.
2. One for the root commit.

Can someone-explain to me why this is happening and if there is a way to overpower this check of deltas between local and remote versions and send only these two packets ?

Comment: Gitolite isn't relevant here (normally anyway). What will matter is if you've made a *shallow* clone: in this case, your own Git can't figure out that it doesn't need to send so much. Make a depth-2 shallow clone and your Git will figure out what it needs to know, and send much less.

Comment: Thank you. I did read about shallow clone but its something we will have to do periodically to keep our repo storing refs. Also everytime I fetch, new refs get added. I was looking for something that could cache things or maybe alter the source code of receive-pack to change packets sending protocol.